TypeError: Undefined type even though I've defined it already
Trying to edit the <Input /> component from shadcn.
import { VariantProps, cva } from 'class-variance-authority';
import { cn } from '@shared/utils';

const inputVariants = cva(
  'flex h-9 w-full rounded-md bg-transparent px-3 py-1 transition-colors file:bg-transparent file:body placeholder:text-muted focus-visible:outline-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        default: '',
        outline: 'border border-input shadow-sm file:border-0 focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring ',
      },
      size: {
        default: 'body',
        lg: 'h4',
        sm: 'tertiary',
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'default',
      size: 'default',
    },
  }
);

export type InputProps = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & VariantProps<typeof inputVariants>;

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(({ className, variant, size, type, ...props }, ref) => {
  return <input type={type} className={cn(inputVariants({ variant, size, className }))} ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
Input.displayName = 'Input';

export { Input };

Not sure why size is undefined here in the IDE (VSCode), even though it should be defined (?). variant works as intended and the code itself runs fine since disabling lint with @ts-ignore shows a smaller sized input as intended.
body, h4 and tertiary are just font size styles fyi.
I've tried reloading the IDE as well, which unfortunately didn't do anything helpful
